# Trying to add USE INDEX to MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below SQL statement and I am trying to add a USE INDEX clause to index on percent and doc_type which I have already added. No matter where I put the USE INDEX (ipercent,idoc_type) clause, it gives me an error say USE is in the wrong place. Any ideas?

```
select name,e_title
from 
(select * from problem2.workson natural join
(problem2.documents,problem2.employees)) as newTable
where percent = 100
and (doc_type = 'internal-report'
or doc_type = 'external-report')
group by name
having count(name) > 1
```

Explain output:
[image]

Comment: one 99.99% (or more) of the time just creates an index, does not force it, and lets the db engine figure it out. Best thing you can do is just stay out of the way, so to speak, and let the db engine determine what is up

Comment: if you need to plop the word `explain` in front of it and run that, and publish that output, that can help us.

Comment: Updated with explain output

Comment: by the way, is it coming back with results in like 1 sec?

Comment: Do you really need to use a natural join?

Comment: I don't see a problem here. From the manual page [How MySQL Uses Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html) : "Indexes are less important for queries on small tables, or big tables where report queries process most or all of the rows. When a query needs to access most of the rows, reading sequentially is faster than working through an index. Sequential reads minimize disk seeks, even if not all the rows are needed for the query."

Comment: then the user tries to intervene, even when good indexes are in place, and does not understand the comment above

Comment: Yeah, I have tried everything, I can't figure out why I am unable to use USE INDEX. No matter where it is in that at statement, it gives me an error say it is in the wrong place.